# What is wrong with my javascript tooltip?

Tags: javascript

I have an issue and I really need your help.
I have a realtime graph with a vertical bar that moves with cursor and i want it to show the value of the graph (d.time and d.value) when the cursor points to. I am trying to get inspired of the tooltip from here: http://bl.ocks.org/WillTurman/4631136 adn that is what I have made: http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/54/ i have two series of data (data1s and data2s) that is generated randomly and I put the time in which the data is generated in "time" variable as you can see:

```css
now = new Date(Date.now() - duration);

var data1 = initialise();
var data2 = initialise();


 //Make stacked data

var data1s = data1;
var data2s = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data1s.length; i++){
data2s.push({
value:  data1s[i].value + data2[i].value,
time: data2[i].time
}  
 )};

 function initialise() {

 var arr = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     var obj = {
 time: Date.now(),
 value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
};
     arr.push(obj);
 }

 return arr;
```

}

When I hover around the graph I want the tooltip show the time and value but it does not recognize it and show "undefined" since I do not know how to pass my datasets (data1s and data2s) so "mouseover function can recognize which data to show! This is how the tooltip functions are made and call from "path1" and "path2".

```
function mouseover() {
     div.transition()
    .duration(500)
    .style("opacity", 1);
}

function mousemove(d) {



 div
  .text( d.time+ ", " + d.value)
  .style("left", (d3.event.pageX ) + "px")
  .style("top", (d3.event.pageY ) + "px");
 }

  function mouseout() {
   div.transition()
  .duration(500)
  .style("opacity", 1e-6);
 }

var path1 = svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .append("path")
    .data([data1s])
    .attr("class", "line1")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);


  var path2 =svg.append("g")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .append("path")
    .data([data2s])
    .attr("class", "line2")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("mousemove", mousemove)
    .on("mouseout", mouseout);
```

Do you have any idea of what to do? As you can see in http://bl.ocks.org/WillTurman/4631136 the layers can be recognized by

```
   svg.selectAll(".layer")
    .attr("opacity", 1)
     .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
      svg.selectAll(".layer").transition()
  .duration(250)
  .attr("opacity", function(d, j) {
    return j != i ? 0.6 : 1;
     })})

.on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
  mousex = d3.mouse(this);
  mousex = mousex[0];
  var invertedx = x.invert(mousex);
  invertedx = invertedx.getMonth() + invertedx.getDate();
  var selected = (d.values);
  for (var k = 0; k < selected.length; k++) {
    datearray[k] = selected[k].date
    datearray[k] = datearray[k].getMonth() + datearray[k].getDate();
  }
```

and the the "mousemove" function can be added for each layer but how can I have this for each of my path?

Thank you,

Comment: change `.on("mousemove", mousemove)` to `.on("mousemove", function(){mousemove(data2s[0])})` see  http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/70/

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but the value (the amount of y axis at that point) that is shown by the tooltip is not correct. When I move the cursor along the path the value that is shown is static which is the last generated random value, not the value for each point, and it is not clear which place it points to. If you click on the graph once it will get paused then you can see how it look likes...

Comment: This is because I used `mousemove(data2s[` **0** `])`,  It should be some kind of variable there, I don't know d3 so i cannot tell you how to get the position where the mouse is and its related data

Comment: Well, I am also new to d3 and I do not know neither . but that is what you recommend: http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/74/ it shows the time of the system but the values are still incorrect. Do you have any other idea ? :)

Comment: By the way that is another graph that and I use circle to show the tooltip. it works fine with the value! http://jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/52/ but the circles are jumpy and I want to remove them but I do not know how. Do you have any idea of how to mix theses code to reach to correct value?

Comment: You should not use 0 because its not the right values, as i told you i don't know d3, but from http://bl.ocks.org/WillTurman/4631136 it looks like he is figuring out the values by looking back to the original data based on the mouse position

Comment: Thank you indeed for your atention! :) I defined two mousemove in order to make it recognize the value of each path: jsfiddle.net/QBDGB/77 but it still does not work for each path! only shows the value of path2!! and I do not know why

Comment: It works for path1 too but only when you hover on its parts that are not covered with path2